# Strategies for suppring calculated Types in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm building a complicated Linq query and I'm running into the problem that "The specified type member 'JobRatio' is not supported in LINQ to Entities".

In my model, Jobs is an IEnumerable:

Job has the following calculated property:

```
public decimal JobRatio
{
    get
    {
        return TotalValueApprovedQuotes == 0 ? 0 : ((TotalValueApprovedQuotes - TotalWorkOrders) / TotalValueApprovedQuotes);
    }
}
```

When I try to set the where clauses from my query based on the user requirement:

```
if (model.ShowJobRatio)
{
    jobs = jobs.Where(x => x.JobRatio < 0.3m);
}
```

I get the error that "The specified type member 'JobRatio' is not supported in LINQ to Entities"

While I realise I can change my IEnumerable to a List to resolve the issue, I actually have a number of these calculated properties to go through and would like to not run the query just yet. (as I'm still building the Where clauses)

One option would be to turn this type into a basic decimal that is precalculated, what are some strategies to address this?  And if I were to calculate this, do I do that on the model? Or in the controller when TotalValueApprovedQuotes,  TotalWorkOrders or TotalValueApprovedQuotes changes?

Comment: You'll have to calculate it in the query, you can't use the property. Also you should add `NotMapped` attribute above that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is code first, you can add a setter to the calculated property to have EF recognise it as a persisted field.

```
public decimal JobRatio
{
    get { return ...; }
    set { }
}
```

Doing this, EF will store the calculated value when you edit and save the entity but it will no be able to populate the value on load so you always have an in-memory up to date value.

However, if the dependency fields are to change outside of this control, your persisted value will be incorrect.

Note that while it's not pretty, ternary operators (`expr ? expr : expr`) are accepted in LINQ to Entities so you can use your calculation in place of `x.JobRatio`.

Comment: That's perfect, I didn't realise you can do that.  How can I iterate through all my objects to calculate this field once I update-database? (jobratio will be 0 until I edit and save an object)

Comment: @RobbieMills I assume you are referring to historic/pre-existing data. Don't over complicate the matter, just write a run-once DB update script and add it to your DB migrations process. Something along the lines of (assuming MS SQL) `UPDATE Jobs SET JobRatio = (TotalValueApprovedQuotes - TotalWorkOrders) / TotalValueApprovedQuotes WHERE TotalValueApprovedQuotes <> 0;`.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the accept, don't forget to upvote. :)